# Tomcat logs configuration

Tags: tomcat

Can you please some suggest me how to change tomcat log file location by default all the logs files are available in tomcat/logs, is there any way to change this location completely.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat Logs

1) tomcat/conf/logging.properties

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs (was)
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = /home/user/logs

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs (was)
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = /home/user/logs

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs (was)
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = /home/user/logs

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = /home/user/logs (was)
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs

2) Server.xml to change localhost.log

was

3) Catalina.sh to change catalina.out log

CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out was

CATALINA_OUT=/home/user/logs/catalina.out

NOTE: Before editing file please do the backup all the 3 files and do the modification, when file is modified please start the tomcat to reflect the changes, Thanks